# SQL Server Function network access rights problem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, networking

I have following Problem:

I wrote c# assembly for SqlServer Function that must delete,copy or move file on internal network computers.

following the code:

```
public Class FunzioniIO
{
    [SqlFunction()]
    public static SqlString DeleteFile (SqlString PathFile)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(PathFile.Value);
            return new SqlString("True");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new SqlString(ex.Message + " \n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Sql Server run under NetworkService on win 2008 server.

When I'm tring to access to one file of one other network comuter giving to him the shared path like

```
'\\\192.168.0.xx\SharedFolder\file.txt'
```

it return the following error:

> Access to the path
>   '\\192.168.0.xx\SharedFolder\file.txt'
>   is denied.

This I think because it try to access like NetworkService and right is refused from FileHosting computer.

I tried to give shared rights on remote computer at first like NetworkService without success and to Everyone at Last but the siuation is the same.

The question is what I must do To enable sql server to remote file access?

Comment: How did you define your assembly in SQL? Did you use `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, and if so does the service account have the permission to run with `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`?

Comment: Yes Permission are with external access

Answer (score 1):

The local NetworkService is actually `DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$` to the share. So permission this account on the share *and* on the underlying NTFS/Samba for that share

Comment: Surely better to create a new domain account for the service rather than promoting the rights of *anything* running under NetworkService

Comment: Sorry But I'm not understand well this means that I Mus Create new User Like ComputerName where ComputerName i the MACHINENAME of sql server?